# Excel Cell reference from equation

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to create a dynamic formula using an equation based on the value of a cell, but I am struggling to find what I need despite having done this before.
For example I have 600 rows in an excel, I want to check something in the last 200 rows only.
I have in D1 for example 600 which relates to the amount of rows. I need to ideally do something like so:

```
SUM(A(D1+1-200):A(D1+1))
```

In other words

```
SUM(A401:A601)
```

I have tried the following as I thought the dollar sign left this as variable, but it is not working for me.

```
SUM($A$(D1+1-200):$A$(D1+1))
```

Unfortunately all searches give me results unrelated to what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: The dollar sign changes a columns or row reference from relative to absolute. What I _think_ you want is `INDIRECT`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use INDEX, which is not volatile:

```
=SUM(INDEX(A:A,D1+1-200):INDEX(A:A,D1+1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("A"&(D1+1-200)&":A"&(D1+1)))
```

[image]

Which, for the case illustrated above, is the same as:

```
=SUM(A1:A201)
```